# Is a spinlock lock free?

Tags: multithreading, lock-free, spinlock

I am a little bit confused about the two concepts.

definition of lock-free on wiki:

> A non-blocking algorithm is lock-free if there is guaranteed
>   system-wide progress

definition of non-blocking:

> an algorithm is called non-blocking if failure or suspension of any
>   thread cannot cause failure or suspension of another thread

I thought spinlock is lock-free, or at least non-blocking. But now I'm not sure. Because by definition, `"spinlock is not lock-free"` also makes sense to me. Like, if the thread holding the spinlock gets suspended, then it will cause suspension of other threads spinning outside. So, by definition, `spinlock` is not even non-blocking, let alone lock-free.

I'm so confused now. Can anyone explain it clearly?

Comment: The usual name for a spinlock that cannot fall back to a lock when spinning didn't pan out is "bug".

Comment: Yup, lock free is one of those unfortunate misnomers that means something completely different than most people think.

Comment: @Voo: What are the most common things people think it means?  wait-free?  Or that it means avoiding library implementations of anything called "lock" (and they don't realize that rolling your own lock with atomics is still a lock)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Anything that can be called a lock (exclude other threads from a critical section until the current thread unlocks) is by definition not lock-free.  And yes, spinlocks are a kind of lock.

If a thread sleeps while holding the lock, no other thread can acquire it and make forward progress, and spinlocks can't prevent this.  The OS can de-schedule a thread whenever it wants, even if it's in the middle of a critical section.

---

Note that "lock-free" isn't the same thing as "wait-free", so a lock-free algorithm can still have stuff like cmpxchg retry loops, but as long as one thread succeeds every time, it's lock free.

A wait-free algorithm can't even have that, and at most has to wait for cache misses / hardware arbitration of contended atomic operations.  Wikipedia's [non-blocking algorithm article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Wait-freedom) defines wait-free and lock-free in more detail.

---

I think you're mixing up two definitions of "blocking".

**I think you're talking about a `spin_trylock` function that *tries* to acquire a spinlock**, and returns with an error if it fails instead of spinning.  So this is non-blocking in the same sense as non-blocking I/O: fail with an error instead of waiting for resource availability.

**That doesn't mean any thread in the system is making forward progress *on the thing protected by the spinlock*.**  It just means your thread can go and do something else before trying again, instead of needing to use separate threads to do something in parallel with waiting to acquire a lock.

---

Spinning in an infinite loop counts as blocking / not-making-progress.  For this definition, there's no difference between a pure spinlock and one that (with OS assistance) sleeps until another thread unlocks.

The definition of lock-free isn't concerned with wasting CPU time / power to make room for independent work to happen.

---

Somewhat related: acquiring an uncontended spinlock doesn't require a system call, which means it's a "light-weight" lock.  Some lock implementations always use a (relatively slow) system call even in the uncontended case.  See [Jeff Preshing's Always Use a Lightweight Mutex](http://preshing.com/20111124/always-use-a-lightweight-mutex/) article.  Also read Jeff's other posts to learn more about lock-free programming, because they're excellent.  So good in fact that the [lock-free] tag wiki links to them.

Comment: @Mave: no, a cmpxchg attempt *will* succeed unless there's interference from another thread.  Very much unlike a spin loop that's waiting for a specific value in memory.  With N threads attempting cmpxchg in lockstep, at least 1 of them will succeed every iteration.  It's impossible for a thread to sleep in a state that makes forward progress for other threads impossible, and livelock is also impossible.   CAS retry loops are "lock-free" but not "wait-free" in formal CS terms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm

Comment: @Mave: No.  If N threads attempt to take a spinlock with xchg at the same time, they can all fail, no forward progress for any thread.  Therefore it's a blocking algorithm, unlike CAS retry loops where the value you're trying to CAS is derived from the previous iteration's CAS-read.  (Also, this is a bad inefficient way of implementing a spinlock.  Spin read-only until you see it unlocked so you don't have N threads spamming atomic RMW operations.  See [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](//stackoverflow.com/a/37246263) for a naive but not terrible x86 asm example.)

Comment: @Mave: The key point: can a thread sleep or die with memory contents left in a state that all other threads get stuck indefinitely?  Yes: blocking algorithm.  No: lock-free.  (But not necessarily *wait-free*.)